# Why can't TypeScript infer a generic type when it is in a nested object?

Tags: typescript

I've got a type that TypeScript can't infer the generic of.

```
interface Foo<A> {
    [name: string] : {
        foo : A
    }
}

function makeFoo<A>(foo: Foo<A>) : Foo<A>{
    return foo
}

// Works fine when manually specifying the types
const manuallyTyped : Foo<string | number> = {
    a: {
        foo: '1'
    },
    b: {
        foo: 3
    }
}

// ERROR, Can't infer type as Foo<string | number>
makeFoo({
    a: {
        foo: '1'
    },
    b: {
        foo: 3
    }
})
```

Originally, I was using the type below but I wanted to make the values of the object objects themselves. Inference works just fine when the indexed signature is flat.

```
interface FlatFoo<B> {
    [name: string] : B
}

function makeFlatFoo<B>(bar: FlatFoo<B>): FlatFoo<B>{
    return bar
}

// Correctly has type FlatFoo<string | number>
const inferred = makeBar({
    a: 'a',
    b: 2
})
```

Does anyone have an explanation and/or a recommendation for getting this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a similar problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249528) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237190).  When TypeScript makes multiple covariant inferences for the same type parameter (in the first example, `number` and `string` for `A`), it tries to pick one of them that is a supertype of the others; it does not infer a union except in the special case where the inferences are literal types of the same primitive type.  If TypeScript appears to infer a union type in other cases, it is because some other language feature is at work.  In the case of `makeFlatFoo`, that feature is the implicit index signature generation for an object literal type, which takes the union of the types of the properties `a` and `b`, which is `string | number`.  `string | number` is matched against `B` and you get a *single* inference of `string | number` for `B` and everything works.  However, in `makeFoo`, the return type of the implicit index signature is `Foo<string> | Foo<number>`.  When this is matched against `Foo<A>`, the union gets broken up and you get *two different* inferences `string` and `number` for `A`.

While the following example based on your answer compiles without error:

```
function makeFoo<A, F extends Foo<A>>(foo: F) : F{
    return foo
}

const result = makeFoo({
    a: {
        foo: '1'
    },
    b: {
        foo: 3
    }
});
```

you'll see that `A` is `{}` and the type of `result` is `{ a: { foo: string; }; b: { foo: number; }; }`, so you haven't succeeded in converting the object to a `Foo<T>` type.  Instead, you could use a type parameter `FA` to capture the return type of the implicit index signature and then use a distributive conditional type to pull out the actual types of the `foo` property, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237897):

```
interface FlatFoo<FA> { 
    [name: string]: FA;
}
type FooPropTypes<FA> = FA extends { foo: infer A } ? A : never;
function makeFoo<FA extends {foo: unknown}>(foo: FlatFoo<FA>) : Foo<FooPropTypes<FA>> {
    return <any>foo
}
```

Comment: Do you have any resources you would recommend? I find myself wondering how I can influence type inference, usually towards union types, pretty often. I'd love something that describes priorities of type inference in difference situations and how to affect it.

Comment: Your web search is as good as mine.  I doubt any such documentation exists; regrettably, it hasn't been a priority for the TypeScript team.  You can [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues) but I doubt anything will happen.  I do know some about type inference and what I don't know, I'm happy to read the source code to learn, so feel free to continue asking specific questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can fix this by updating `makeFoo` to capture the entire input as a generic.

```
function makeFoo<A, F extends Foo<A>>(foo: F) : F{
    return foo
}
```

Its not exactly what I expected but the structural typing works out.